# How and why is ap defined as liftM2 id in Haskell

Tags: haskell, applicative

Whilst trying to better understand Applicative, I looked at the definition of <*>, which tends to be defined as ap, which in turn is defined as:

```
ap                :: (Monad m) => m (a -> b) -> m a -> m b
ap                =  liftM2 id
```

Looking at the type signatures for liftM2 and id, namely:

```
liftM2  :: (Monad m) => (a1 -> a2 -> r) -> m a1 -> m a2 -> m r
id                      :: a -> a
```

I fail to understand how just by passing in id, the relevant part of the type signature seems to transform from `(a1 -> a2 -> r) -> m a1` to `m (a -> b)`. What am I missing here?

Comment: Perhaps the spelling `ap = liftM2 ($)` would be more illuminating.  It means the exact same thing.

Comment: @luqui: Just for the guys who don't know, `($)` is just `id` specialized to functions.

Comment: @fuz, your comment was illuminating! [A question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47317555/is-there-a-relationship-between-dollar-sign-and-id-function-in-haskell) was also asked, years ago.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The type variable `a` from `id` can be instantiated at any type, and in this case that type is `a -> b`.

So we are instantiating `id` at `(a -> b) -> (a -> b)`. Now the type variable `a1` from `liftM2` is being instantiated at `(a -> b)`, `a2` is being instantiated at `a`, and `r` is being instantiated at `b`.

Putting it all together, `liftM2` is instantiated at `((a -> b) -> (a -> b)) -> m (a -> b) -> m a -> m b`, and `liftM2 id :: m (a -> b) -> m a -> m b`.

Comment: I had to read through that a few times to get it to click, but it's finally starting to. Thanks for answering.

Answer (score 3):

The top answer is definitely correct and works quickly and efficiently from the types alone. Once you are good at Haskell (disclaimer: I am not) then this is a much more efficient way to understand this than to slough through the function definitions.

But since I recently had to struggle through exactly this issue with `ap` while I was working on [The Monad Challenges](http://mightybyte.github.io/monad-challenges/), I decided to share my experience because it may provide some extra intuition.

First, just as The Monad Challenges asks, I will use the name `bind` to refer to the primary Monad operator `>>=`. I think this helps a lot.

If we define our own version of `liftM2` we can do this:

```
liftM2 :: (Monad m) => (a -> b -> c) -> m a -> m b -> m c
liftM2 f ma mb = 
    ma `bind` \a -> 
    mb `bind` \b -> 
    return $ f a b
```

We want to create `ap` using this to help us. Let's leave the function `f` alone for a moment and just think about how this could work as `ap` assuming we picked the right function for `f`.

Suppose that we were to pass a function-valued Monad as the first part above, the `ma` part. It could be something like `Just (+3)` or `[(+3), (*2)]` -- some "function" living inside a Monad context.

And we supply an argument-valued Monad as the second part, the `mb` part, such as `Just 5` or `[6,7,8]` -- some "value" living in a Monad context which can serve as the argument for the function living inside `ma`.

Then we'd have

```
liftM2 f (m someFunction) (m someArgument) = 
    (m someFunction) `bind` \a ->
    (m someArgument) `bind` \b ->
    return $ (f a b)
```

and inside the lambda functions following `bind`, we know that `a` will be `someFunction` and `b` will be `someArgument` -- for that is what `bind` does: it simulates the extraction of a value out of the Monad context modulo any special processing that is unique to that Monad.

So that final line really becomes

```
return $ f someFunction someArgument
```

Now let's step back and remember that our goal in creating `ap` is to call `someFunction` upon `someArgument` inside of the Monad context. So whatever our use of `return` yields, it needs to be the result of the function application `someFunction someArgument`.

So how can we make the two expressions be equal

```
f someFunction someArgument ==? someFunction someArgument
```

Well, if we let `x = (someFunction someArgument)` then we're looking for a function `f` such that

```
f x = x
```

and so we know that `f` needs to be `id`.

Going back to the start, this means we're looking for `liftM2 id`.

Basically `liftM2 id ma mb` says I'm going to do `m (id a b)` so if `a` is a function that can operate on `b`, then `id` will "just leave them alone" and let `a` do its thing to `b`, while returning the result inside of the Monad context.

It's like we've forced `liftM2` to have bystander bias.

And in order for that to work out, `a` will have to have a function type that goes from "TypeOfb" to "SomeReturnType", or `TypeOfb -> SomeReturnType`, because `b` is `a`'s expected argument. And of course `b` has to have `TypeOfb`.

If you'll permit me one abuse of notation, then *arbitrarily* let's just use the symbol "a" to stand for "TypeOfb" and the symbol "b" to stand for "SomeReturnType":

```
`b` --> "a" is its type
`a` --> "a -> b" is its type
```

Then the type signature for `ap` would be

```
ap :: Monad m => m (TypeOfB -> SomeReturnType) -> m TypeOfB -> m SomeReturnType
==>
ap :: Monad m => m (a -> b) -> m a -> m b
```