# How much is applicative really about applying, rather than "combining"?

Tags: haskell, type-constraints, applicative, category-theory

For an [uncertainty-propagating `Approximate` type](https://github.com/leftaroundabout/uncertainly-haskell/blob/master/Data/Uncertain.hs), I'd like to have instances for `Functor` through `Monad`. This however doesn't work because I need a vector space structure on the contained types, so it must actually be restricted versions of the classes. As there still doesn't seem to be a standard library for those (or is there? please point me. There's [rmonad](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/rmonad), but it uses `*` rather than `Constraint` as the context kind, which seems just outdated to me), I wrote [my own version](https://github.com/leftaroundabout/constrained-categories) for the time being.

It all works easy for `Functor`

```
class CFunctor f where
  type CFunctorCtxt f a :: Constraint
  cfmap :: (CFunctorCtxt f a, CFunctorCtxt f b)  => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b

instance CFunctor Approximate where
  type CFunctorCtxt Approximate a = FScalarBasisSpace a
  f `cfmap` Approximate v us = Approximate v' us'
   where v' = f v
         us' = ...
```

but a direct translation of `Applicative`, like

```
class CFunctor f => CApplicative' f where
  type CApplicative'Ctxt f a :: Constraint
  cpure' :: (CApplicative'Ctxt f a) => a -> f a
  (#<*>#) :: ( CApplicative'Ctxt f a
             , CApplicative'Ctxt f (a->b)
             , CApplicative'Ctxt f b)        => f(a->b) -> f a -> f b
```

is not possible because functions `a->b` do not have the necessary vector space structure* `FScalarBasisSpace`.

What does work, however, is to change the definition of the restricted applicative class:

```
class CFunctor f => CApplicative f where
  type CApplicativeCtxt f a :: Constraint
  cpure :: CAppFunctorCtxt f a  => a -> f a
  cliftA2 :: ( CAppFunctorCtxt f a
             , CAppFunctorCtxt f b
             , CAppFunctorCtxt f c )        => (a->b->c) -> f a -> f b -> f c
```

and then defining `<*>#` rather than `cliftA2` as a free function

```
(<*>#) = cliftA2 ($)
```

instead of a method. Without the constraint, that's completely equivalent (in fact, [many `Applicative` instances go this way anyway](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5358868/how-and-why-is-ap-defined-as-liftm2-id-in-haskell)), but in this case it's actually better: `(<*>#)` still has the constraint on `a->b` which `Approximate` can't fulfill, but that doesn't hurt the applicative instance, and I can still do useful stuff like

```
ghci> cliftA2 (\x y -> (x+y)/x^2) (3±0.2) (5±0.3)        :: Approximate Double 
0.8888888888888888 +/- 0.10301238090045711
```

I reckon the situation would essentially the same for many other uses of `CApplicative`, for instance the `Set` example that's already given in the [original blog post on constraint kinds](http://blog.omega-prime.co.uk/?p=127).

### So my question:

is `<*>` more fundamental than `liftA2`?

Again, in the unconstrained case they're equivalent anyway. I actually have found `liftA2` easier to understand, but in Haskell it's probably just more natural to think about passing "containers of functions" rather than containers of objects and some "global" operation to combine them. And `<*>` directly induces all the `liftAμ` for *μ* ∊ ℕ, not just `liftA2`; doing that from `liftA2` only [doesn't really work](https://github.com/leftaroundabout/constrained-categories/blob/master/Control/Applicative/Constrained.hs#L77).

But then, these constrained classes seem to make quite a point for `liftA2`. In particular, it allows `CApplicative` instances for all `CMonad`s, which does *not* work when `<*>#` is the base method. And I think we all agree that `Applicative` should always be more general than `Monad`.

What would the category theorists say to all of this? And is there a way to get the general `liftAμ` without `a->b` needing to fulfill the associated constraint?

---

**Linear functions* of that type actually do have the vector space structure, but I definitely can't restrict myself to those.

Comment: If you add the `FScalarBasisSpace` restriction to the `Approximate` constructor, you don't need any context for `<*>`, because you can get the type class constraints by pattern matching on the input values.

Comment: @SjoerdVisscher: good point, I probably should use GADTs much more. However, I'm not sure if I really want `FScalarBasisSpace` as a constraint on _all_ kinds of uncertainties. I sure need it to implement the obvious instances... I'll think about it.

Comment: @SjoerdVisscher ... also, thinking about it the GADT constraint doesn't quite solve my problem, because `Approximate(a->b)` would become impossible to start with. I would need a separate constructor for this case, which seems quite ugly to me right now, though perhaps it's not that bad, if I properly hide it from the module interface.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As I understand it (as a non---category theorist), the fundamental operation is `zip :: f a -> f b -> f (a, b)` (mapping a pair of effectful computations to an effectful computation resulting in a pair).

You can then define

- `fx <*> fy = uncurry ($) <$> zip fx fy`
- `liftA2 g fx fy = uncurry g <$> zip fx fy`

See this [post by Edward Yang](http://blog.ezyang.com/2012/08/applicative-functors/), which I found [via the Typeclassopedia](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Typeclassopedia#Alternative_formulation).

Comment: I believe the canonical definitions would be something like `fzip :: (f a, f b) -> f (a, b)` and `unit :: () -> f ()`--i.e., taking the monoidal structure of product types and lifting that into the functor. Those would be horribly awkward to use, though.

Comment: In that case, shouldn't it be `class (Monoidal f) => Alternative f where { join :: f (a, a) -> f a }`, with `a <|> b = join (zip a b)`?

Comment: @Tinctorius: No, you generally don't want `x <|> y` to be equivalent to `f <$> x <*> y` for some `f`--otherwise, what would be the point of having `Alternative`?

Comment: With dave4420's definition for `<*>`, that would only be the case when `join` is equivalent to `(<$>) (f . uncurry ($))` for some `f`. Since `join` generally isn't structure-preserving, that's not necessarily true, right?