# What means precisely "function inside a functor"

Tags: haskell, category-theory

In category theory *functor* is a homomorphism between two categories. In Haskell, it's said that *applicative functor* allows us to apply functions *"inside a functor"*. Could one translate that words *"function inside a functor"* back to mathematics or give some other insight? (I know that functor can be `Maybe`, `[]` etc. but still struggle to comprehend that notion.)

Comment: Related: [How much is applicative really about applying, rather than “combining”?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13625905/how-much-is-applicative-really-about-applying-rather-than-combining) (where I still don't really have the answer to my question, but the mathematical nature of applicative is touched quite a bit)

Comment: @leftaroundabout Excellent, and more advanced question on the similar topic. Thanks for the link.

Comment: Does looking at the type of "the" key component of an applicative functor `(<*>)` help (`Applicative f => f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b`), or are you looking for something "deeper" than that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My category theory is not strong at all (I started from the programming side of Haskell and have been recently trying to learn some of the category theory foundations of some of its concepts). But here's what I've got:

In Haskell, a functor is a type constructor, meaning it maps from general types to "types in the functor".

In category theory, a functor maps from the objects of one category to the objects of another category.

When applying category theory to Haskell, we imagine that we're working with the category **Hask**, the category of Haskell types.

So Haskell functors aren't general category theory functors; they all map from **Hask** to a sub-category of **Hask** (because the type `f a` for some functor `f` and arbitrary type `a` is *still* a Haskell type). For example the `Maybe` functor maps objects (types) in **Hask** to the category of types of the form `Maybe a`.

Functions are first-class in Haskell, so function types are perfectly ordinary types (and are objects of **Hask**) so functors *also* map function types to "function types in the functor". So the phrase "a function inside a functor" is a shorthand for a *value* in a type that results from applying a functor to a function type. e.g. `Just (+1)` is one particular value in the type `Maybe (Int -> Int)`, which is the object (type) to which the `Maybe` functor maps the object `Int -> Int`.

So an "applicative functor" is a functor which has some extra rules, which are sufficient to take *values* which are functions in types which are objects of the functor's "destination" category, and apply those values to other values in types in the destination category.

Using `Maybe` again as an example, if we only knew it was a functor that gives us a correspondence between the objects `Int -> Char` and `Maybe (Int -> Char)`, and between the objects `Int` and `Maybe Int`, and between the objects `Char` and `Maybe Char`. But while we have the ability to take a value in `Int -> Char` and a value in `Int` and produce a value in `Char`, `Maybe` being a functor doesn't guarantee that we have any ability to do some corresponding operation with a value in `Maybe (Int -> Char)` and a value in `Maybe Int`.

When we also know it's an applicative functor, then we do have an ability to take a value in `Maybe (Int -> Char)` and a value in `Maybe Int` and produce a value in `Maybe Char`, and this satisfies certain properties wrt the application of `Int -> Char` values to `Int` values.

As far as I know, applicative functors aren't terribly interesting from a pure category theory standpoint. Perhaps this is because category theory is concerned with relationships between *objects*, which correspond to types in Haskell, but from a programming perspective applicative functors are motivated by relationships between *values* in those types? (we want the values in the "function types" obtained by using the functor to still be able to be applied to things to do computation).

Answer (score 3):

**Translation Back to Math**

In a closed monoidal category there is a notion of "exponent" which "internalizes" the morphism relation.  You can then evaluate these exponents.  That is, you have a way of saying (excuse my notion, Stackoverflow lacks mathjax)

```
eval : (a ~> b,a) -> b
```

as well as meta operations for currying and uncurrying.
An "applicative functor" maps exponents in an "applicable" way, `F (a ~> b)` can be combined with an `F a` to get an `F b`.  This is because applicative functors are monoidal functors, so they have an operation (in the target category)

```
f a -> f b -> f (a,b)
```

which when you also fmap eval gives you `ap` from Haskell.

I doubt that was usefull,

**The Haskell**

The best way to understand an applicative functor is to look at the type

```
class Functor f => Applicative f where
  pure :: a -> f a
  <*>  :: f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

the trivial example is

```
newtype Id a = Id a
instance Applicative Id where
  pure a = Id a
  Id f <*> Id a = Id (f $ a)
```

`Id` is also a `Monad`.  In fact, all `Monad`s are `Applicative`.

```
pure = return
mf <*> mx = do f <- mf
               x <- mx
               return (f x)
```

a more interesting example though is infinite sequences

```
data Seq a = Seq a (Seq a)
instance Applicative Seq where
  pure a = Seq a (pure a)
  (Seq f fs) <*> (Seq x xs) = Seq (f x) (fs <$> xs)
```

You can think of this as being equivalent to `zipWith $` on lists.  All `Monad`s are `Applicative`, but I think the infinite sequence is fun because the corresponding monad instance is...non obvious (and rather slow). It will be left as an exercise to the reader (btw, I am steeling this example/exercise from something I remember reading that I think pigworker wrote on this site).

Comment: In the definition of `Applicative`, shouldn't be there `<*>` instead of `<$>`?

Comment: I know I'm coming late to the party but shouldn't `eval : (a ~> b,a) -> a` be `eval : (a ~> b,a) -> b`?

Comment: @raichoo indeed.  Fixed.